# Empty storage bag deformation

Tags: modeling

I'm totally new to Blender, but what I heard is Blender could be usefull for my question. I'm trying to model storage bags for a vehicle, but I don't know how to do that, in order to deform them when they are empty. Any suggestions?
[image: Photo]

Comment: did you try cloth simulation?

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but didn't know how to start

Comment: by finding some tutorials, I mean writing the whole answer down would be a bit long, you just need to use one-sided cube with open top and extruded edge, you need to pin the top with vertex group, set some good settings for hard cloth, and later subdivide it and solidify it, it is possible and quite easily, you just need guidance